# Variable equals variable will not work

Tags: php

Right now im working on my signup and activation email, i have one problem it will not send the email, yes i have tested it, i have set

```
$to = 'myemail@example.com';
```

to my email before and it has worked but when i have

```
$to = $e;
```

it doesnt work
i have check and it does make the email the user puts in into a variable which is $e
so i have no idea what the problem is if someone can help that would be great

heres the mail form:

```
 mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

EDIT:
here is my whole mail code

```
 $to = $e;                           
    $from = "auto_responder@mywebsite.com";
    $subject = 'Account Activation Success';
    $message = '<html>Success</html>';
    $headers = "From: $from\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    echo "signup_success";
    exit();
```

EDIT x2:
I feel this will never be found out
i even tried this

```
 $to = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['e']);
```

which post['e'] is the email the user put in

EDIT x3
after some test i noticed something
when i do

```
 $to = 'myemail@gmail.com';
```

it doesnt send
but with

```
$to = 'myemail@hotmail.com';
```

it works so i guess its not sending to gmails?

Comment: If `$to = $e;` then `$to` does not equal `$e` ;-)

Comment: Could you provide a bit more of your code? It's difficult to answer your question without more context.

Comment: Why not just save the email address to $to in the first place?

Comment: More code has been added

Comment: Likely it will work if you do `$e = 'myemail@example.com'; $to = $e;`

Comment: What I meant earlier, is that you need to change `mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);` to `mail($e, $subject, $message, $headers);` - You're assigning `$t` to be `$e`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i have tried that i really dont know whats going on because i was thinking that $e could be getting messed up in some place but it works everywhere else

Comment: @Fred-ii- is there a email i can just send you the  file at?

Comment: http://pastebin.com if your code is too big for here.

Comment: @Fred-ii- http://pastebin.com/XujB2HTf if you need more tell me

Comment: Did you not try changing `mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);` to `mail($e, $subject, $message, $headers);`? You can also try `$e = $_POST['e'];` instead.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to get the 'e' query parameter from a form submission.  If that's the case, try this:

```
$to = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'e', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
```

If your form uses POST, then swap in INPUT_POST instead of INPUT_GET.  If you don't care about filtering or don't have the filter extension, you could just do this, which works with both GET and POST.

```
$to = $_REQUEST['e'];
```

Comment: check comments under my answer, he already confirmed that value is there. so something magic is there :-)